# CSS super advanced nth-child selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm currently working on a photo gallery with pagination. It shows the main image and also a list of thumbnails, something like this:

```
+----------------------+----+----+----+---+----+
|                      |  1 |  2 |  3 | 4 |  5 |
+                      +----+----+----+---+----+
|      MAIN IMAGE      |  6 |  7 |  8 | 9 | 10 |
+                      +----+----+----+---+----+
|                      | 11 | 12 | 13 | < |  > |
+----------------------+----+----+----+---+----+
```

Please note the numbers in the thumbnail container are a number assigned to each image, NOT the actual position in the container.

The thumbnails I have them inside a list container, so they are targeted using `ul > li` selectors.

So, my problem is that I need to give different margins to the list items containing my images, depending on the position in their container, for example:

`margin-left: 0px` for images 1, 6, and 11

`margin-right: 0px` for images 5, 10 and the > character at position 15

So, I'm able to do part of what I need, by using :nth-child selector, something like this:

```
ul li:nth-child(5n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}

ul li:nth-child(5n+5) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The problem comes when I go to the next page of thumbnails, my `<` and `>` links I have to move them from page 1 to page 2, and then hide all thumbnails in page 1 to show the ones in page 2, so the selectors no longer apply... it's complicated, so it's better to show what page 2 would look like:

```
+----------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
|                      | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
+                      +----+----+----+----+----+
|      MAIN IMAGE      | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
+                      +----+----+----+----+----+
|                      | 24 | 25 | 26 |  < |  > |
+----------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

So, now my selectors won't work, instead of applying to images 15, 20 and 25 for the left margin and 21, 26 and the `>` link for the right margin, they apply to 14, 19, 24 for one margin, and 18, 23 and the `>` link for the other.

My first approach was to target only the visible items, but that can't be done via CSS, and I really don't want to go the jQuery road unless absolutely necessary - layout should be done via CSS alone, right?

So, there it is, that's what I can't figure out.

One idea I had was to target 5n+1 and 5n+5 in ranges of 13 items at a time, and then target my pagination links separately, but I can't find the way of doing that, here's what I tried so far:

```
:nth-child(13n):nth-child(5n+1)
:nth-child(13n+1):nth-child(5n+1)
:nth-child(5n+1):nth-child(13n+1)
```

I guess my idea can be explained as "target every fifth item starting from item 1, and then every fifth item starting from item 5, and repeat the same calculation in ranges of 13 items (1-13, 14-26, 27-39, and so on)"

Anyone knows how I can accomplish that?

Thanks

** UPDATED WITH THE SOLUTION **

Thanks to @Dekel for pointing me in the right direction.

Here's the final CSS I used to make it work

```
ul li:not(.psr_paging):nth-child(13n-12),
ul li:not(.psr_paging):nth-child(13n-7),
ul li:not(.psr_paging):nth-child(13n-2) {
  border-color: cyan;
  margin-left: 0;
}

ul li:not(.psr_paging):nth-child(13n-8),
ul li:not(.psr_paging):nth-child(13n-3) {
  border-color: blue;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#pager-next {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

And here's a working sample of the thing working as expected:

On codepen: https://codepen.io/andruxnet/pen/ozvEBW?editors=1111

And here:

```js
var page = 0; 
var numThumbs = 13;
var paging = [
  {'start': 1, 'end': 13},
  {'start': 14, 'end': 26},
  {'start': 27, 'end': 39}
];

function refreshThumbs() {
  var startIndex = paging[ page ].start - 1;
  var stopIndex = paging[ page ].end - 1;

  // Show/Hide thumbs
  var $thumbsUl = $('ul.thumbs');
  $thumbsUl.find('li:not(.psr_paging)').each(function(i) {
    var $li = $(this);
    if ( i >= startIndex && i <= stopIndex ) {
      $li.show();
    }
    else {
      $li.hide();
    }
  });
  $('#pager-prev').insertAfter($('ul.thumbs').find('li:visible:not(.psr_paging):last'));
  $('#pager-next').insertAfter($('#pager-prev'));
}

$('#pager-next').on('click', function() {
  if ( page < 2 ) {
    page++;
    refreshThumbs();
  }
});

$('#pager-prev').on('click', function() {
  if ( page > 0 ) {
    page--;
    refreshThumbs();
  }
});
```

```css
.thumbs-wrap {
  width: 460px;
  height: 360px;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.thumbs-wrap ul.thumbs {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.thumbs-wrap ul.thumbs li {
    width: 18%;
    height: 74px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.thumbs-wrap li.thumb-blank {
    background-color: red;
}

.thumbs-wrap li.psr_paging a {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.thumbs-wrap li.psr_paging a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:not(.psr_paging):nth-child(13n-12),
ul li:not(.psr_paging):nth-child(13n-7),
ul li:not(.psr_paging):nth-child(13n-2) {
  border-color: cyan;
  margin-left: 0;
}

ul li:not(.psr_paging):nth-child(13n-8),
ul li:not(.psr_paging):nth-child(13n-3) {
  border-color: blue;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#pager-next {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbs-wrap">
  <ul class="thumbs">
    <li class="thumb-blank">1</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">2</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">3</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">4</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">5</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">6</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">7</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">8</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">9</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">10</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">11</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">12</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank">13</li>
    <li id="pager-prev" class="psr_paging">
      <a class="thumb pageLink prev" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="pager-next" class="psr_paging">
      <a class="thumb pageLink next" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">14</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">15</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">16</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">17</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">18</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">19</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">20</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">21</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">22</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">23</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">24</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">25</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">26</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">27</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">28</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">29</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">30</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">31</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">32</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">33</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">34</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">35</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">36</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">37</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">38</li>
    <li class="thumb-blank" style="display: none;">39</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you hiding/showing the elements when the navigation buttons are clicked?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML? It's not clear how the < and > links appear in the HTML from the question.

Comment: I'm looping through the list items inside the container using $('ul li').each(), I then do $(this).show() for the ones where their position in the list container is inside the correct range, for page 1 the range is 1-13, for second page is 14-26, end so on

Comment: sorry it took this long, I wanted to clean up the html from images and stuff... here it is in codepen, hopefully you can see it: https://codepen.io/andruxnet/pen/ozvEBW?editors=1111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with pure CSS, using `:nth-child`

Each "block" of `li` elements you have contains 13 elements, so you can use the `13n+X` in the `:nth-child` selector.
Now what you need to do is subtract the number of `li` elements from the 13n you got. The first one will be `13n-12` (to get 1), the second will be `13n-7` (to get 6) and the last will be `13n-2` (to get 11).

Here is the working version:

```css
ul {
  width: 115px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li:nth-child(13n-12),
ul li:nth-child(13n-7),
ul li:nth-child(13n-2) {
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li>
  <li style="clear: left">14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li> <li>18</li> <li>19</li> <li>20</li> <li>21</li> <li>22</li> <li>23</li> <li>24</li> <li>25</li> <li>26</li>
  <li style="clear: left">27</li> <li>28</li> <li>29</li> <li>30</li> <li>31</li> <li>32</li> <li>33</li> <li>34</li> <li>35</li> <li>36</li> <li>37</li> <li>38</li> <li>39</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could add the other requirement to your answer as well @Dekel [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/z0n0pmbm/)

Comment: @RicardoRuiz, he said that the `<` and `>` are moved between the pages so I wasn't sure they are in the `li` and part of the "real" dom. But you are welcome to upvote my answer if you find it correct/useful/interesting ;)

Comment: mmmm looks interesting, I'll test that approach and tell you how it goes

Comment: Thank you, @Dekel, your answer sent me in the right direction, not the way I expected but it did get the job done! I'm updating my question with the working CSS and a link to the codepen for reference.